# CosmosDB stored procedure 400

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm writing an expire stored procedure that works off of the date a document was entered into cosmosDB. I'm using the SQL Api as well. I'm able to execute the stored procedure and recall it using the continuation model, but randomly the stored procedure fails and I have no clue why.

Here is the error I get with the

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
---> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: 
{"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error   
 Stack trace:    
 at Anonymous function (purgeStaleActivity.js:40:24)
 at Anonymous function (purgeStaleActivity.js:839:29)"]}  

 ActivityId: 5f32323e-619f-4a50-b073-5edbd41c6357, Request URI: /apps/6628b461-75d4-4e4a-9897-ada4076dc30c/services/883314f1-064a-4921-9202-b5d8ca905550/partitions/832a92d6-a846-4e32-b18d-194f7c14ff85/replicas/131674305234651764p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.21.0.0, Windows/10.0.16299 documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.9.1  
 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ClientExtensions.d__1.MoveNext()  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.c__DisplayClass20_0.b__0>d.MoveNext()  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0>d.MoveNext()  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__3.MoveNext()  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.  d__3.MoveNext()  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__1.MoveNext()  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  
 at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.d__20.MoveNext()  
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.d__12.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__256.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__219`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__1.MoveNext()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
       at UserQuery.Main() in C:\Users\A750501\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad5\_bingnjxc\query_vbrkkj.cs:line 51
    ---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error\r\nStack trace: Error\n   at Anonymous function (purgeStaleActivity.js:40:24)\n   at Anonymous function (purgeStaleActivity.js:839:29)"]}
    ActivityId: 5f32323e-619f-4a50-b073-5edbd41c6357, Request URI: /apps/6628b461-75d4-4e4a-9897-ada4076dc30c/services/883314f1-064a-4921-9202-b5d8ca905550/partitions/832a92d6-a846-4e32-b18d-194f7c14ff85/replicas/131674305234651764p, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.21.0.0, Windows/10.0.16299 documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.9.1
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ClientExtensions.d__1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.c__DisplayClass20_0.b__0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.d__20.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.d__12.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__256.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.d__219`1.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.d__1.MoveNext()
```

Here is my stored procedure to delete:

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample(expireTime) {
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    var responseBody = {
        deleted:0,
        continuation: true
    };

    if(!expireTime) throw new Error("The expireTime must not be null");

    tryAndDelete();

    function tryAndDelete(continuation){
        var requestOptions = {continuation: continuation};

        var isAccepted =  __.filter(function(doc) {return doc.creationDate <= expireTime}, function(err, feed, responseOptions){
        if(err) throw err;

        if(feed.length > 0) {
            tryDelete(feed);
        }
        else if(responseOptions.continuation){
            tryAndDelete(responseOptions.continuation);
        }
        else {
            responseBody.continuation = false;
            response.setBody(responseBody);
        }
        });

        if(!isAccepted) {
            getContext().getResponse().SetBody(responseBody);
        }
    }

   function tryDelete(documents){
       if(documents.length > 0 ) {
           var isAccepted = __.deleteDocument(documents[0]._self, {} , function(err,responseOptions){
               console.log(err);
               if(err) throw err;

                responseBody.deleted++;
                documents.shift();
                tryDelete(documents);

           });

           if(isAccepted){
               response.setBody(responseBody);
           }
       }
       else {
             tryAndDelete();
       }
   }
}
```

I have tried to run this in the data explore to try and get the  console.log  and using the requestoptions  to enable script logging but the exception get thrown before I have a chance to read the console log on the portal or examine the response object logs.

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the TTL feature? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/time-to-live

Comment: no TTL reset every time the document is changed.  We only want documents to live for 30 days after they were created.

Comment: We ended up just making an azure function that wiill return 100 document to be expired.  If there are 100 documents we know that function need to run again so we just make another call to that function to run until less than 100 documents are returned  for the expireDate